# Polygons in CSV, WKT coordinate order

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

I have a text file with the data:

```
98923|Place1|31.144562;33.741344:31.171932;33.873543:31.103771;33.884808:31.073994;33.786865
342342|Place2|36.995064;7.632923:36.995880;7.849720:36.832218;7.848527:36.832191;7.633185
```

So I managed to create the coordinate string into a WKT format

```
POLYGON ((31.144562 33.741344,31.171932 33.873543,31.103771 33.884808,31.073994 33.786865))
POLYGON ((36.995064 7.632923,36.995880 7.849720,36.832218 7.848527,36.832191 7.633185))
```

I imported them into QGIS but they are in the wrong location as coordinates are in the wrong order?

Any ideas how I could fix this as my file have thousands of records

Comment: Are the pairs Long-Lat or Lat-Long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `swapxy` plugin which claims to do exactly this.

Its in the plugin repository, and is trusted.

Here is a brown set of features, which when `swapxy` runs on them, produce the blue features, which are reflected in the Y=X line, which is the diagonal that runs between them.

[image]

Comment: Don't thank me, thank the plugin developer!