# Why QGIS using different coordinate order depending on import type GML / CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, import, gml, order

I am using QGIS 3.20 (Odense)

I am importing same polygons from GML3 and also from a CSV file.

In GML, all geometries are assigned a single coordinate system EPSG:2180 (`srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180"`)

In CSV, geometry is described in WKT: `MULTIPOLYGON (((381005.10404459015 650243.6918136529, 381010.7832707977 650259.8074660491,... )))` and when importing CSV I also choose EPSG:2180 coordinate system.

In both .gml and .csv the values are stored in the same order, yet after importing the csv layer is created with longitude and latitude switched.

How to obtain the same output and what I am doing wrong?

[image: two different outputs from importing GML and CSV]

I am aware of this answer: [Polygons in CSV, WKT coordinate order](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273578/polygons-in-csv-wkt-coordinate-order) but it does not explain why there is a difference.

Comment: Does the CSV WKT have any axis ordering in it, are the coordinates stored in easting/northing order (EPSG:2180 is nothing/easting).

Comment: @nmtoken I must admit this is very confusing for a GIS newbe like me. So if I get this correctly: EPSG:2180 --> northing/easting --> WKT should have coords in Y X order. WKT I've put in CSV were generated using NTS (.Net JTS) which is always using X Y.

Comment: @nmtoken But why GML does not behave the same way?

Comment: Probably the answer is that the coordinates are stored in northing/easting order, and when QGIS opens the GML it makes no assumption on axis order, and thus displays it correctly.  For CSV though it may make an assumption that the default for WKT is easting, northing, and in displaying it, the coordinates are incorrectly flipped